# Java recursive calls

Tags: java, recursion

I want to build a code to go over any sequence of 0 and 1 and calculate how many different ways it can pass through the number just "jumping" between the '1's. Also it can jump no more than 3 digits per time.

For example, number 100110101 it could be like:
1xx1xx1x1 or 1xx11x1x1 (passing through all the '1').

Another example could be 1011011101:
1x11x111x1 (passing through all '1') or 1xx1x111x1 or 1x1xx1x1x1 and so on...

The important is not to jump more than 3 digits.
And the number will always start and finish with 1 as well.

I've got the following code and I think it is working.

```
public int calculate(String number){

        if(number.length()<3){ //left fill with 0 
            if(number.length()==2) number = "0" + number;
            else number = "00" + number;
        }

        if(number.length() == 3){ //for 001, 101, 011, 111
            if (number.equalsIgnoreCase("111")) return 2; //2 possible ways
            else return 1; //any other combination will have just one way
        }

        String aux = number.substring(1,4);//take the 3 next digits
        
        //recursive calls to calculate it
        if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("001")) return calculate(number.substring(3, number.length()));
        else if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("010")) return calculate(number.substring(2, number.length()));
        else if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("011")) return calculate(number.substring(2, number.length())) + calculate(number.substring(3, number.length()));
        else if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("100")) return calculate(number.substring(1, number.length()));
        else if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("101")) return calculate(number.substring(1, number.length())) + calculate(number.substring(3, number.length()));
        else if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("110")) return calculate(number.substring(1, number.length())) + calculate(number.substring(2, number.length()));
        else if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase("111")) return calculate(number.substring(1, number.length())) + calculate(number.substring(2, number.length())) + calculate(number.substring(3, number.length()));

        return 0;
    }
```

The question is: I also wanna make sure that it is not allowed to jump 3 digits twice in a row. Something like 1xx1xx1 is not allowed. However since I'm using recursive calls I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent jumping 3 digits twice in a row is to pass extra state information to `calculate()`; the extra data you pass would be a boolean indicating whether or not the last jump was of length 3. Then in your initial call to `calculate()`, just make sure to indicate that the last jump was not of length 3 (so the first jump is allowed to be of length 3).

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static int countPossibilities(String inputString) {
            final char validChar = '1';
            final char maxDistance = 3; // max consecutive jumps. eg: maxDistance for '1xxx1' is 3.

            if (inputString.length() == 1) {
                return 1;
            }
            var indexForMaxPossibleJump = Math.min(maxDistance + 1, inputString.length() - 1);
            if (inputString.charAt(indexForMaxPossibleJump) != validChar) {
                indexForMaxPossibleJump = inputString.substring(0, indexForMaxPossibleJump).lastIndexOf(validChar);
            }

            // No jumps possible.
            if (indexForMaxPossibleJump == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int finalCount = 0;
            var remainingString = inputString.substring(indexForMaxPossibleJump);
            var maxJumpingString = inputString.substring(1, indexForMaxPossibleJump);

            // calculate count if we are not jumping to max distance. i.e., taking intermediate step on 1.
            for (var i = 0; i < maxJumpingString.length(); i++) {
                if (maxJumpingString.charAt(i) != validChar) {
                    continue;
                }
                var countOfString = countPossibilities(maxJumpingString.substring(i) + remainingString);
                finalCount += countOfString;
            }

            // calculate count if we are jumping to max distance.
            var countOfRemainingString = countPossibilities(remainingString);
            finalCount += countOfRemainingString;
            return finalCount;
        }
```